# How to create a nested group of custom marker in eclipse marker view

Tags: eclipse

it's possibile to create a level of nesting in the marker to view the custom marker ?
Es:

--> Group A

```
   ----> subGroup 1

           ----> subGroup 2
```

--> Group B

```
   ----> subGroup 1

           ----> subGroup 2
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for nested markers. You can have multiple markers on the same line, and you can define different types of marker.

You could possibly use additional attributes of the marker that you define to specify relationships between markers, but the standard Eclipse code would not know anything about that.